# smbj: How can I get subdirectories only?

Tags: java, samba, smb, smbj

I use https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj for samba access.
I want get only the subfolders of my target directory.
Whith following code I get "..", "." and all the files - is there an elegant way to get subdirectories only?

```
SmbConfig config = SmbConfig.builder().withMultiProtocolNegotiate(true).build();
    smbClient = new SMBClient(config);
    Connection connection = smbClient.connect(smbServerName);
    AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(smbUser, smbPassword.toCharArray(), smbDomain);
    Session session = connection.authenticate(ac);
    share =  (DiskShare) session.connectShare(smbShareName);    
    List<FileIdBothDirectoryInformation> subs = share.list("mydirWhichSubDirsIwant");
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with smbj, but did you try to use other smb libs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to filter out the results from the returned list. If you only want the subdirectories you can get them as follows:

```
List<String> subDirectories = new ArrayList<>();
for (FileIdBothDirectoryInformation sub: subs) {
    String filename = sub.getFileName();
    if (".".equals(filename) || "..".equals(filename)) {
        continue;
    }
    if (EnumWithValue.EnumUtils.isSet(sub.getFileAttributes(), FileAttributes.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
        subDirectories.add(filename);
    }
}
```